# Android studio not starting

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed android studio to my pc but thats not starting. Only show starting window.

My pc os - windows 11 ,  Ram 8gb

I have updated java version.
Checked java paths.
Tried multiple time by unistall and installing.

**Could you please help me for resolve this? **

Comment: :), have a look here https://youtu.be/Qicn7BZNYp8

Comment: I followed the above steps but not worked.